# Am I fundamentally misunderstanding the net input dot product w*x

Tags: regression, logistic, perceptron

Most books have the notation of a weight vector w and input matrix x:
$$
w = \begin{bmatrix}
w_1\\...\\ w_D
\end{bmatrix},
x = \begin{bmatrix}
x_{11}&...&x_{1D}\\
...&...&...\\
x_{N1}&...&x_{ND}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
For N samples and D features/parameters. Then it goes on to say the net input, or y prediction, or whatever the book decides to call it, is
$$
y=w^Tx
$$
But doesn't that mean every sample of the 1st feature is multiplied with weights $w_1, w_2,...w_D$? Intuition tells me it should be each $d$-th feature should be multiplied by the correspnding $d$'th weight, done over all samples. By this reasoning it should be more like $y=xw$, which I've definitely never seen in any of the books. What am I getting wrong?

PS I realized I missed the bias; hopefully the argument still stands.

Comment: As written, the dimensions aren't compatible for multiplication: $w^T$ is $1 \times D$ and $x$ is $N\times D$, so the product $w^T x$ isn't defined unless $N = D$. Writing $y = x w$ is in this context is correct, and it written that way in many places

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula your "most books" give cannot be right because, in general, $N \neq D$. Consequently, you cannot multiply a row vector of length $D$ with a matrix containing $N$ rows. Thats simple linear algebra.

Comment: Using this as an example (p.11, or 9/30 slide number), is the prof incorrect?
http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~rgrosse/courses/csc321_2018/slides/lec02.pdf

Comment: I just realized later in slide 11/30 (p. 14) it is written Xw... I dont even go to the school so I'm not sure if the prof corrected himself mid-lecture. I guess since my confusion was justified, then it's ok I understand now...

Comment: I see no proof on slide 9/30. But I admit, the notation may be misleading, because it mixes vectors and one-dimensional matrices. You can consider both $w^T$ and $x$ to be vectors, so $w^T x$ is simply a dot product. If you understood them as one-dimensional matrices ($x$ a single-row matrix, $w$ a single-column matrix), you'd need to write $x w$. On the slide 11/30, where multiple observations are collected as rows in the matrix $X$ (capital X!), this is actually the notation used: $X w$.